# Explain this rewrite rule?

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have managed to put this condition and rule below together to redirect a page to include index.shtml at the end of it but I dont understand what this part of the Rewrite means - the `^$` part.  I believe `^` means start and `$` is end but in this context I dont understand its meaning in "English" and how it works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.test\.com [NC]  
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example1.test.com/index.shtml [R,L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is the start of the string, `$` is the end. If there's nothing in between, as in the case of `^$`, that means an empty string. Since the path leading up to the current directory is ignored, the part of the URL that matches is *after* the `http://www.example1.test.com/`. Matching an "empty string" *after* that means matching the URL itself, as in: with no file or anything else specified. So, this redirects the root URL to index.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If a user visits the exact URL `www.example1.test.com` he or she is redirected to `http://www.example1.test.com/index.shtml`.

Useful tool: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: Thanks...so ^$ is saying match "everything from start to end of  www.example1.test.com" and apply index.shtml to it ?

Comment: Nice link, i was always telling to test for regexp here: http://www.quanetic.com/Regex